# Problem with Team Foundation Server Builds

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

We have several project collections in TFS2010 and one particular collection is getting the following error.

> TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition \xxxxx\xxxx Test Build: The request channel timed out while waiting for a reply after 00:04:59.9843751. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

I'm fairly new to TFS and would appreciate and pointers in the right direction.

Comment: This should be part of a longer exception message. It's saying that some WCF operation tool longer than 5 minutes to complete. Is your build controller running?

Comment: I can confirm that the build controller is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED!!!! Our Build Servers talk to our App Tiers through NLB. Just checked the NLB Config and found that one of the App Tiers NIC's had reverted to a 169.x.x.x address. Removed from NLB, Reconfigured NIC, Added to NLB, All working!!!

Comment: Yes, it appears that this message is essentially saying "your build agent is down". Similar case with us - the agent was hung for some reason. Rebooting it cleared up the message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the diagnostic build output?

Queue New Build -> Parameters Tab -> Logging Verbosity -> Diagnostic.  After it builds, post the relative log file section.

I can give you a pretty solid guess at this point; however, with that information we should be able to tell exactly what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Slightly confused on this one, if the build fails the only log we get is what I have posted above.  I'm guessing to are saying that you need a Build to complete and you would like to see that log?

Comment: When you queue the build in TFS you can get detailed information on what happened.  Even if it fails at the start this will give you more information about the issue.  Please queue a new build this way and tell us the log output.  Does that make sense?

Comment: When you say project collections do you mean actual TFS collections or are you just saying a group of projects.  Builds are not related TFS collections. Please clarify.

Comment: They are actual TFS Collections with a number of projects inside.

Comment: Just out of interest whats you "solid guess"?

Comment: One thing we have discovered is that if we change the setting in the Build Service to not use the FQDN and just the machine name, builds seem to rum fine!

Comment: That would not have been my guess :)  I have had that happen though in the past where TFS couldn't pick up what was happening with my controller as it thought it was offline due to the use of the FQDN.  That happened because someone else used the baseline Hyper-V I created (which had the same machine name) and added it to the domain so on our domain we two PCs with the same name.  A little different than your scenario though perhaps.  So are you gtg on this or are you still struggling to finalize your builds?

Comment: It far more stable than before after changing the setting in the Build Service to not use the FQDN but we stil have a few failures, with two particular errors. One is the same error as before and the other is as follows

Comment: TF215097: An error occured while initializing a build for build definition \Gateway2.0\2.7_Gateway. There was no endpoint listening at http://ggtfs26build1.9191/Build/v3.0/Services/Controller/21 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: SOLVED!!!!  Our Build Servers talk to our App Tiers through NLB.  Just checked the NLB Config and found that one of the App Tiers NIC's had reverted to a 169.x.x.x address.  Removed from NLB, Reconfigured NIC, Added to NLB, All working!!!

Comment: Cool you should write your own answer and accept it so that it may help others in the future.